# Flexbox horizontal alignment: Make content fit - including pseudo element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a set of flexboxed divs. I would like them to adjust automatically depending on the width.
Using `flex: 1 1 auto` on the children, it seems to work for text, but not for each text's pseudo element (in this case, the arrow). What do I need to do to make the flexbox include the width of the flexbox as well?

Html:

```
<div class="entries">
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Longer</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Longest</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Looooongest</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.entries {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #901a1e;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.entry {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 11px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f3f3f1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3f3f1 0%, #edece9 100%);
  position: relative;
}

.entry a {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

.entry>a:before {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -18px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  color: #901a1e;
  content: '>';
  font-weight: 700;
}

.entry+.entry:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #901a1e;
}
```

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/dLwqjtrg/) - narrow the window: The arrow of the last div will disappear instead of making the first div shrink...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dLwqjtrg/1/ this is what you want?

Comment: mostly because your arrow is absolutely positioned, you would need to remove absolute positioning to make flex count it in div width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, the anchor and its pseudo is not part of the Flexbox itself, it is only the `entries` (flex container) and the `entry` (flex items) that are flex elements.

The reason why the arrow gets hidden is that the pseudo is absolute positioned and as such it won't be taken into account when the anchor's size is calculated (an absolute positioned element is taken out of flow), which will indirect affect how Flexbox calculate the size for the `entry`

If you add a left padding on `a` and change `left` to `0` on the pseudo it will work.

*See notes in CSS*

```css
.entries {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #901a1e;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.entry {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 11px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f3f3f1;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f3f3f1), to(#edece9));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3f3f1 0%, #edece9 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3f3f1', endColorstr='#edece9', GradientType=0);
  position: relative;
}

.entry a {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  padding-left: 18px;                      /*  added  */
}

.entry>a:before {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;                                 /*  changed  */
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  color: #901a1e;
  content: '>';
  font-weight: 700;
}

.entry+.entry:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #901a1e;
}
```

```html
<div class="entries">
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Longer</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Longest</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Looooongest</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Since you already use Flexbox, you can use it to solve the issue you have and vertically center the text/arrow by making the anchor `a` a flex container.

*See notes in CSS*

```css
.entries {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #901a1e;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.entry {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 11px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f3f3f1;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f3f3f1), to(#edece9));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3f3f1 0%, #edece9 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3f3f1', endColorstr='#edece9', GradientType=0);
  position: relative;
}

.entry a {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;                /*  added  */
  align-items: center;                 /*  added  */
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

.entry>a:before {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #901a1e;
  content: '>';
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-right: 5px;                  /*  added  */
}

.entry+.entry:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #901a1e;
}
```

```html
<div class="entries">
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Longer</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Longest</a>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <a href="#">Looooongest</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo-element in a flex container is a flex item.

A flex item that is absolutely-positioned is removed from the document flow and no longer accepts flex properties.

So if you want your pseudo item to behave like the DOM items, don't use absolute positioning.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items

Comment: Note though, the pseudo is _not_ a flex item, nor is the anchor a flex container, so the issue has little to do with Flexbox, so I was considering to remove that tag from the tag list

Comment: Well, now I also added a solution using Flexbox, so I guess it is better the tag list stays as it is :)